# Are there any way to write single line in following typecript code?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to write this code in a single line using typescript? This code contains within for each function. Only one element of this for each Type =Type.NO_NEED_INCREASE.Other elements need to increase variable value.

```
      let order: number;
      if (model.type !== Type.NO_NEED_INCREASE) {
        order+= 1;
      }
```

Comment: Should `model.tpye` be `model.type` and are `order` and `productOrder` meant to be the same variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following code:

```
let order: number = -1;
if (model.type !== Type.NO_NEED_INCREASE) {
  order += 1;
}
```

It can be flattened using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to:

```
let order = model.type === Type.NO_NEED_INCREASE ? -1 : 0;
```

Depending on how you use `order`, you may be able to make use `const` instead of `let`.

Note that I removed the explicit typing to `number` as it is unnecessary.

Comment: let order: number = -1; , within for each loop, every time assing -1 being so , not increment value.